# How do I use the Firebase library in a command line C++ program?

Tags: c++, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've built a web app that uses the Firebase Authentication service to manage user accounts. I need to now build a C++ program that will allow those same users to sign into their accounts. The C++ program will just be interfaced through the command line on a Unix system. My problem is Firebase apparently supports C++, but its in the context of game development for iOS or Android, which I learned from the guide here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup?platform=ios. Is what I am trying to do possible? I have downloaded the Firebase C++ library, but I am not sure what to do with it. If I can include the Firebase headers in my program, how do I provide configuration information so it can access my Firebase project (api key, projectId, etc)? Which library files do I need to provide to the C++ compiler?

Comment: "I am not sure what to do with it..." This is "Using libraries in C++ 101" which is an extremely common use-case. You will need to find a reference here on building that library and linking it in to your application, but the good news is this is routine.

Comment: I've been trying to find someone else who has done this online, but haven't had much success. Theres a CMakeList file I found in the sdk. Would that be useful?

Comment: Then that's a CMake project, so you'll need to familiarize yourself with that to be able to build it. There's going to be a learning curve here. You just need to push through it. Good news is CMake is very commonly used.

Comment: Ok I've been getting CMake figured out and it isn't too bad. Can you explain why I even need to use CMake in the first place to add a library to my project? Why can't I just copy/paste the files that I need in my project's directory?

Comment: Short answer: That's not how C++ works. Long answer: It's rarely as simple as copy-pasting code and things magically work out. Many libraries have non-trivial build steps and must account for the quirks of your compiler and/or operating system. These libraries aren't intended to work on just your computer, but on a multitude of computers and compilers. Getting that to work out requires a tool like `Configure` or CMake.

Comment: I see. Thanks for you help!

Comment: I wrote a tutorial for doing this (Firebase on Desktop): https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-add-firebase-to-your-c-desktop-game-4a177703186e . Note that desktop support is _very beta_ and intended for use in development (see this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup#desktop-workflow ). Your results will be mixed: Firestore has full feature parity, Auth is pretty good, but Analytics is completely missing and will just no-op (rather than error -- it's intended to not get in the way during development).